# Solrj NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, solr

I'm using Solr to perform search on database. I added the following dependency in my pom.xml but it didn't work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I got a runtime error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams

I got this solved by putting the entire library under the WEB-INF/lib folder. However it confused me why the maven dependency didn't work.
I'm using tomcat 8.0.

Comment: Try to clean both the Tomcat temp folder and the war and rebuild from scratch with `mvn clean install`.

Comment: What is value in the `<packaging>` tag within your `pom`? You haven't included a `<scope>` tag within the the `solr-solrj` `<dependency>`, so the default `scope` (`compile`) was applied. This means that the related artifact (usually a JAR file) is needed both during the build and at runtime, so the artifact should have been included in your deployment package. The `NoClassFoundError` means that the related artifact was not present at runtime, which is why putting the library in `WEB-INF/lib` resolved the problem. The root problem is likely within your `pom`. Can you add the full contents?

Comment: so what should I do with the <scope> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the jars (libraries) referenced in the application should be available in the application's library path at run time. In your POM you have defined what all libraries or packages you are using. The default repository for POM is `~/.m2/respository` where it keep all the references jars.

Now you need to provide them at rum time as well. When you do `mvn clean install` for any application, by default it packages only application source code not all the libraries. These are called `Thin jar's`, because they contain only application code and light weight.

To access them at runtime, you need to either create a `Fat jar`, which will bundle all the jars defined in your POM file or you need to add them to application `lib` path.

By putting them into `WEB-INF/lib`, you are adding all the jar into applications lib path, which is a default lib path for tomcat.